# My transparency for my button isn't working. I am also trying to add a border

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

button_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

My button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_one"
    android:layout_width="356dp"
    android:layout_height="251dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:alpha="0.50"` in your  layout xml and try it out.
or 
also try it out : `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

See this link for better understanding: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html for border related issues.